# Splitting data into subsamples

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy

I have a huge dataset which contains coordinates of particles. In order to split the data into test and training set I want to divide the space into many subspaces; I did this with a for-loop in every direction (x,y,z) but when running the code it takes very long and is not efficient enough especially for large datasets:

```
particle_boxes = []


init = 0
final = 50
number_box = 5

for i in range(number_box):
    
    for j in range(number_box):
        
        for k in range(number_box):

            index_particle = df_particles['X'].between(init+i*final, final+final*i)&df_particles['Y'].between(init+j*final, final+final*j)&df_particles['Z'].between(init+k*final, final+final*k)
        
    
            particle_boxes.append(df_particles[index_particle])
```

where `init` and `final` define the box size, `df_particles` contains every particle coordinate (x,y,z).

After running this `particle_boxes` contains 125 (number_box^3) equal spaced subboxes.

Is there any way to write this code more efficiently?

Comment: can you show your sample input and expected output? I know its harder (for you) to provide a sample and easier o show your code but without any context it's very difficult to give you an accurate solution.

Comment: Is this a job for a **k-d tree** ?

Answer (score 3):

### Note on efficiency

I conducted a number of tests using other tricks and nothing changed substantially.  This is roughly as good as any other technique I used.

I'm curious to see if anyone else comes up with something order of magnitude faster.

#### Sample data

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df_particles = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(250, size=(1000, 3)),
    columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z']
)
```

---

#### Solution

Construct an array `a` that represents your boundaries

```
a = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250])
```

Then use `searchsorted` to create the individual dimensional bins

```
x_bin = a.searchsorted(df_particles['X'].to_numpy())
y_bin = a.searchsorted(df_particles['Y'].to_numpy())
z_bin = a.searchsorted(df_particles['Z'].to_numpy())
```

Use `groupby` on the three bins.  I used trickery to get that into a `dict`

```
g = dict((*df_particles.groupby([x_bin, y_bin, z_bin]),))
```

We can see the first zone

```
g[(0, 0, 0)]

      X   Y   Z
30    2  36  47
194   0  34  45
276  46  37  34
364  10  16  21
378   4  15   4
429  12  34  13
645  36  17   5
743  18  36  13
876  46  11  34
```

and the last

```
g[(4, 4, 4)]

       X    Y    Z
87   223  236  213
125  206  241  249
174  218  247  221
234  222  204  237
298  208  211  225
461  234  204  238
596  209  229  241
731  210  220  242
761  225  215  231
762  206  241  240
840  211  241  238
846  212  242  241
899  249  203  228
970  214  217  232
981  236  216  248
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I tried it out and I get very big problems with the memory; since I have millions of particles in the data set my computer dies everytime I run it with boundary a=np.arange(0,280,10). 
Furthernmore: since I want to use these subboxes seperately can I somehow access and save them?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiple nested `for` loops, consider one loop using `itertools.product`. But of course avoid any loops if possible as @piRSquared [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60724345/1422451):

```
from itertools import product

particle_boxes = []

for i, j, k in product(range(number_box), range(number_box), range(number_box)):

    index_particle  = (df_particles['X'].between(init+i*final, final+final*i) & 
                       df_particles['Y'].between(init+j*final, final+final*j) & 
                       df_particles['Z'].between(init+k*final, final+final*k))

    particle_boxes.append(df_particles[index_particle])
```

Alternatively, with list comprehension:

```
def sub_df(i, j, k)
   index_particle  = (df_particles['X'].between(init+i*final, final+final*i) & 
                      df_particles['Y'].between(init+j*final, final+final*j) & 
                      df_particles['Z'].between(init+k*final, final+final*k))

   return df_particles[index_particle]

particle_boxes = [sub_df(i, j, k) for product(range(number_box), range(number_box), range(number_box))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function available in the `scikit-learn lib`.

I think it is almost the kind of functionality that you need.

The code is consultable on Github.